# Bootstrap 4 drop down menu not dropping

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am coding my website from scratch and I've run into a road block. I cannot get this drop down menu to drop using this Bootstrap 4 framework. The Drop Down menu is the alternative for the mobile devices, or smaller screens... the version used for the larger devices has a totally different html which is in the mock up below.

I also find that my initial load content does not display on the mobile device? I don't know if this is from my ajax code or whatever.

You can check out the website for testing via 
https://trillumonopoly.com/testing/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark fixed-top nav2"  style="background-color:#202020!important;" height="30" >

<div class="dropdown show d-block d-xl-none">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="color: #202020" href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    menu
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <ul id="navMenu">
                        <li><a href="home"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="artist"><span>TALENT</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="services"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="music"><span>MUSIC</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="shop"><span>BEATS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="media"><span>VIDEOS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact"><span>CONTACT US</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

  <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive d-none d-md-block" height="30" width="30"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-10">ILLUMONOPOLY</div></div>
</nav>
        <div class="container2 d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="menu-wrap container-fluid">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <div class="link-list container-fluid scrollx">
                        <center> 
                        <ul id="navMenu">
                        <li><a href="home"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="artist"><span>TALENT</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="services"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="music"><span>MUSIC</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="shop"><span>BEATS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="media"><span>VIDEOS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact"><span>CONTACT US</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </center>
                    </div>

                </nav>
            </div>
            <button class="menu-button" id="open-button"><img src="img/menu3.png" height="42" width="42"><span>Open Menu</span></button>
                <div class="container-fluid"> 
                    <div id="main">

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
```

Here's my Ajax/jQuery code as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main').load('pages/home.php');

        $('ul#navMenu li a').click(function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
            return false;
        }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you include Bootstrap's JS file before including jQuery as it says in the console too: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.`

Include jQuery first, and only include Bootstrap's JS file after that. It should fix your problem.

Comment: You also have to include Popper.js: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)` A link is on the [official website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/)